# Why must a safe configuration be reached in `n^2 + n` rounds in Dijkstra's Self-stabilizing mutual exclusion algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

In the book *Self-Stabilization* (Dolev, 2000) the author provides a proof (p.19) of Dijkstra's self-stabilizing mutual exclusion algorithm. An excerpt of the book showing the proof is found below.

[image: proof of Dijkstra's self-stabilizing mutual exclusion algorithm]

At the end of the proof for *Theorem 2.1*, the author states

> In accordance with lemma 2.4, *P1* must assign *j* to *x1* in every
> *n^2* rounds. Thus a safe configuration must be reaches in *n^2 + n* rounds.

I do not understand this conclusion. Furthermore, lemma 2.4 says that a safe configuration must be reached in *n* rounds, not *n^2* rounds. So where does the *n^2* come from in the statement "In accordance with lemma 2.4, *P1* must assign *j* to *x1* in every *n^2* rounds."?

---

Let's try and walk through the proof bit by bit and see if we can understand it.

The proof starts with reiterating lemma 2.3 which states

> for every possible configuration c there exists at least one integer `0 <= j <=  n` stuch that for every `1 <= i <= n`, `xi != j` in c.

This lemma is simple enough to understand. According to the pigeonhole principle (also known as *Dirichlet's principle*) it is natural that such a number *j* does not exist within the system. This as the system can at most hold *n* distinct integers (e.g. a unique integer for every processor) out of `n + 1` possible. Earlier in the text it istated that "Each processor *Pi* has a variable xi that stores an integer value that is no smaller than `0` and no larger than `n`." Hence there are `n + 1` numbers, but only n processors.

Moving forward the author continues with reiterating lemma 2.4 which states

> ... for every possible configuration c, in every fair execution that
> starts in c, the special processor *P1* changes the value of *x1* in every *n* rounds.

This is also fairly easy to understand due to the nature of the transition functions for the processors. Processor *P1* increments it's state *x1* if (and only if) `x1 == xn`. This happens after at most every *n* rounds as it requires that many rounds for the state of *P1* to propagate to all the other processors.

The author continues by stating

> Every time *P1* changes the value of *x1*,
> *P1* increments the value of *x1* modulo `n + 1`. Thus, it must hold that every possible value, and in particular the value *j*, is
> assigned to *x1* during any fair execution that starts in c.

I do not understand this part, nor the following part

Let *cj* be the configuration that immediately follows the first assignment of *j* in *x1*. Every processor *Pi* `2 <= i <= n` copies the value of `xi-1` to *xi*. Thus, it holds for `1 <= i <= n` that `xi != j` in every configuration that follows *c* and precedes *cj*; it also holds that in *cj*, the only *x* variable that holds the value *j* is *x1*.

The next part I understand

> *P1* does not change the value of [..]. Let *cn* be the configuration reached following the assignment of `xn = j`. *cn* is a safe configuration.

Then the final conclusion comes, which is the main point I am trying to understand as stated in the beginning.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.